# Upper-triangular matrices as semidirect product

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G=GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Consider
the set $U_{n}$ of upper-triangular matrices of $G$ having entries of $1$ on
the diagonal. The cardinality of $U_{n}$ is $p^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ and $U_{n}
$ is a subgroup of $G$, \ in particular $U_{n}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G
$. Is it true that $U_{n}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n-1}\rtimes
U_{n-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Indeed, the idempotent endomorphism described in block matrices as $p:\begin{pmatrix} A & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}A& 0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ defines such a semidirect decomposition $\mathrm{Ker}(p)\rtimes\mathrm{Im}(p)$.